# Crypto++ DefaultEncryptor/DefaultDecryptor scheme

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am trying to encrypt a file using AES with crypto++. I can see the functions EncryptFile and DecryptFile which use DefaultEncryptorWithMAC/DefaultDecryptorWithMAC from test.cpp in crypto++.

```
void EncryptFile(const char *in, const char *out, const char *passPhrase)
{   
    FileSource f(in, true, new DefaultEncryptorWithMAC(passPhrase, new FileSink(out)));
}

void DecryptFile(const char *in, const char *out, const char *passPhrase)
{
   FileSource f(in, true, new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(passPhrase, new FileSink(out)));
}
```

However I want to use AES and as far as I understand the default encryption scheme is DES_EDE2. Is there a build in way to handle this?

I don't need a MAC so something similar to the DefaultEncryptor/DefaultDecryptor class pair would be good enough.

Also I would prefere to use a random SecByteBlock instead of a passphrase as the following

```
// Generate a random key
SecByteBlock key(0x00, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
rnd.GenerateBlock( key, key.size() );
```

Comment: So what is your problem. What have you tried so far. I guess you can start of from the this [example](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and then start to look at `BufferedTransformation` if you want to use the FileSource/FileSink.

Answer (score 0):

> However I want to use AES and as far as I understand the default encryption scheme is DES_EDE2. Is there a build in way to handle this?

The project changed the defaults. The commit of interest is [Commit bfbcfeec7ca7](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/bfbcfeec7ca7a0487978391803496a1d4aada37c), and the issue of interest is [Issue 345](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/345). It will be available in Crypto++ 5.7. 
For those who need the old algorithms, they can use `LegacyEncryptor`, `LegacyDecryptor`, `LegacyEncryptorWithMAC` and `LegacyDecryptorWithMAC`.

The `Mash` function was retained to keep things less complicated. If these were new classes, they would have used `HKDF` to extract and expand the entropy; and used PBKDF to grind over the derived key. Since both old and new needed support, we opted for the single source solution. As far as I know, the mash function meets the security goals.

If you are *not* using Master, then you can also change the following typedfs in `default.h` to suit your taste. However, you will need to recompile the library afterwards:

- `typedef DES_EDE2 DefaultBlockCipher;`
- `typedef SHA DefaultHashModule;`
- `typedef HMAC<DefaultHashModule> DefaultMAC;`